# When does Regina stop being the mayor of Storybrooke?

Tags: plot-explanation, once-upon-a-time

When does Regina stop being the mayor? I mean, when does she pass her duties to Mary Margaret?

Answer (score 4):

Mary Margaret became Mayor in the episode ["White Out"](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/White_Out), the 2nd episode of Season 4.

> A blackout strikes the town. David and Emma investigate the issue at
>   the border as Mary Margaret stays home. Unexpectedly, Granny, Happy
>   and Leroy persuade her into fixing the power issue. She balks, as this
>   is a task for the mayor, but they believe Regina no longer wants the
>   job. Granny stresses that Mary Margaret cast the last curse, so she
>   must step up. Additionally, Leroy recalls they reclaimed her kingdom
>   in the Enchanted Forest, but Storybrooke is her kingdom now, so she
>   has to rule it.

Clip of the appropriate scene:

This deleted scene from the same episode has Regina passing the mayorship over to Snow (instead of the townspeople):